# Shortcut of zooming out in Notes

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, notes.app

I am using a french keyboard in MacBook Pro. The followings are shortcuts in `Notes`. `Zoom In` works perfectly, whereas `Zoom Out` by `Shift + command + ,` does not work.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: I'm on an iMac with High Sierra. Works for me except on images in a note.

Comment: What system are you running?

Comment: i am running the same system, but i use a french keyboard...

Comment: Is the comma key next to the period key on a french keyboard?

Comment: @jmh Yes, comma is on the left of period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of a bug, `shift` + `command` + `,` is equal to the command that checks grammar/misspelled words (`command` + `;`).
To fix it, follow this [link](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25377?locale=en_US) to a guide, but as Application, select Notes, and as Menu Title, type `Zoom Out`, and in the Keyboard Shortcut field, do any key combination you like, log out of your user account, log in again, and you’re done...